# Modbus RTU permanent Timeout Error with galvanic isolated RS485 connector

Tags: modbus, permanent, timeouterror

i have some problems with my Modbus RTU communication.

After many polls (50.000+) with Modbus Poll software as master and only one device connected to the bus with the configuration 9600 Baud, 8 Databits, no Parity, 1 Stop Bit i get a permanent Timeout Error with my galvanic isolated rs485 connector. I did measurements with an oscilloscope and my galvanic isolated rs4854 connector.

The following picture shows the result:

[Galvanic isolated rs485 connector, fails after some thousand polls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XbrJ.png)

First look at this picture and the voltage levels seems correct. It seems that the last byte is the only thing that could lead to a permanent timeout error with the galvanic isolated rs485 connector?

I tried some other Modbus RTU configurations but this fails as well and i get a permanent Timeout Error with my galvanic isolated rs485 connector.

Furthermore i did measurements with a non galvanic isolated rs485 connector / my galvanic isolated rs485 connector with A and GND connected.

The following pictures showing the results:

[Galvanic isolated rs485 connector with A and GND connected, works fine for million+ polls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPlEy.png)

[Non galvanic isolated rs485 connector, works fine for million+ polls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUW29.png)

First look at this pictures and voltage levels seems correct and there is no extra byte at the end of the Rx packet.